# How to create a Uuid with static lifetime?

Tags: rust

I want to have a static Uuid in my Rust program but I am unable to figure out how to do it.

I tried this but it does not work

```
fn type_id() -> &'static uuid::Uuid {
    let tmp = "9cb4cf49-5c3d-4647-83b0-8f3515da7be1".as_bytes();
    let tmp = uuid::Uuid::from_slice(tmp).unwrap();
    &tmp
}

error: cannot return reference to local variable `tmp`
returns a reference to data owned by the current function (rustc E0515)
```

Comment: You probably want something like [`once_cell:Lazy`](https://docs.rs/once_cell/1.9.0/once_cell/sync/struct.Lazy.html) or [`lazy_static`](https://docs.rs/lazy_static/latest/lazy_static/)

Comment: Are you trying to create a uuid with a static lifetime because an error message told you to? Often, there are other/better ways to resolve those errors.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy No. There is this uuid value that is a constant that I need to use in my code.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Assuming you're using [the `uuid` crate](https://docs.rs/uuid), several of the "constructor" functions are `const`. So you can just call them "normally" to initialise your static (which is a const context).

Sadly the playground doesn't have `uuid` but I figure something along the lines of:

```rust
static TYPE_ID: Uuid = Uuid::from_u128(0x9cb4cf49_5c3d_4647_83b0_8f3515da7be1);
```

or using the `hex_literal` crate if you prefer something more string-looking:

```rust
static TYPE_ID: Uuid = Uuid::from_bytes(hex!("9cb4cf49 5c3d 4647 83b0 8f3515da7be1"));
```

Comment: It works. That looks much better!

Answer (score 1):

Thanks @PitaJ. Using once_cell:Lazy works. I am still curious to know if there is a simpler way of doing this so I won't mark the answer as accepted yet.

```
static TYPE_ID: Lazy<uuid::Uuid> = Lazy::new(|| {
    let tmp = "9cb4cf49-5c3d-4647-83b0-8f3515da7be1";
    let tmp = uuid::Uuid::from_str(tmp).unwrap();
    tmp
});
```